# Firebase let authenticated user create their own user entry

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I wanted to know if it's possible that a newly authenticated user can insert **only** their information to the realtime database.

The flow would be something like:

1. User authenticates via my app where he has to input

- Email
- Username
- ...

2. The user is authenticated (via Firebase Authentication) and has a `uid`
3. User writes a new DB entry in the `/users/{uid}` field of his/her. However, they are not allowed to set the balances field below.

- Email
- Username
- ...

He/She should only be able to write and read his/her own `/users/{uid}` object.

###### I've tried these rules so far, but none of them lets me create a new `/users/{uid}`

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "balances": {
          ".write": false
        },
        "userName": {
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        },
        "email": {
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        },
        "phoneNumber": {
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid", 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

###### The code I want to insert:

```swift
// ...

Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
    if let error = error {
        self.error = error.localizedDescription
        return
    }
                    
    if let authResult = authResult {
                        
    // Auth successful
    User.firebaseUser = authResult.user
    print("Firebace UserId: \(authResult.user.uid)")
    let ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()
    
    ref.child("users").child(authResult.user.uid).setValue([
        "userName": self.userName,
        "email": self.email
    ])
                        
    // ...

    }
}
```

###### My Swift error message:

> 2022-05-26 16:55:55.043864+0200 Project[15240:1265346] 9.0.0 - [FirebaseDatabase][I-RDB038012] setValue: or removeValue: at /users/EZ2bNl3rMANtLtn1G9Wfqi0Ivjl1 failed: permission_denied

Thank you in advance!

Comment: These rules look fine for [content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#realtime-database_2), so most likely the problem is in the code you use to write the data. Please edit your question to include the [minimal code with which you can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code and error message now :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've got it working now. The problem was, that I had some subcategories which the user was not allowed to set. I however did a full on replacement of the object. Is there anything like a batched write for firebase realtime db? This would circumvent my problem. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Batched requests in Realtime Database as multi-path writes. Put the full paths to update in a `Map`, and then call `ref.updateChildren` with that map.